# I get an uncaught error after running my code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am working on a project and every time node run my code the browser console gives me this :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "express". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

It says this line gives me the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

I don't know why do I keep getting this error. Please help. Thank you.

**And I have npm installed 'express', 'node-fetch' and 'esm'.**

This is my main.js file:

```
import express from 'express';

import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const { clientID, clientSecret, port } = require('./config.json');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', async ({ query }, response) => {
    const { code } = query;

    if (code) {
        try {
            const oauthResult = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
                method  : 'POST',
                body    : new URLSearchParams({
                    client_id     : clientID,
                    client_secret : clientSecret,
                    code,
                    grant_type    : 'authorization_code',
                    redirect_uri  : `http://localhost:${port}`,
                    scope         : 'identify'
                }),
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            });

            const oauthData = await oauthResult.json();

            const userResult = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
                headers : {
                    authorization : `${oauthData.token_type} ${oauthData.access_token}`
                }
            });

            console.log(await userResult.json());
        } catch (error) {
            // NOTE: An unauthorized token will not throw an error;
            // it will return a 401 Unauthorized response in the try block above
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return response.sendFile('index.html', { root: '.' });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

And this is my start.js:

```
// file start.js
require = require('esm')(module /*, options*/);
module.exports = require('./main');
```

Comment: have you tried using require instead of import syntax?

Comment: yes i have but it gives me error that require is not defined.

Comment: like this? : ```const express = require("express");```

Comment: Yes cause i am using node.js

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://medium.com/threejs/module-specifiers-versus-relative-import-references-fd747980ba6f) ?

Answer (score 0):

the first thing you need to do is, install one bundler (parcel), then you need develop your package.json script which serve from parcel

Comment: C:\Users\aryan_0m0ox0n\Desktop\DSS Website\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:845: Cannot statically evaluate fs argument.

It is giving me this error

Comment: content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'ascii'). For this line.

Comment: just tell parcel you're running in a node environment with the target flag

e.g. parcel app.js --target node

Comment: I did it now I am getting this error:

`Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`